# ASP.net MVC integrated security migrating to OKTA multifactor authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, okta

I have an ASP.net mvc application with integrated security and I wish to migrate it to OKTA multi factor authentication. I have made some proof of concept and everything seems to be find but I have doubts about how to configure IIS since I don't want IIS to force the user to login with a valid Active Directory account. Leaving IIS with anonymous authentication I get what I want but is it a good practice? I think it's kind of insecure.

Comment: By "migrate it to Okta multi factor authentication" do you mean that all of your authentication will be handled by Okta, or just the second factor challenge?

Comment: Yes, all authentication will be handled by Okta.

Comment: How are you doing Okta authentication from ASP.NET? OpenID Connect, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research seems that leaving IIS accepting anonymous authentication is the right thing to do since  the request cames from an unrecognized/unauthorized origin therefore the IIS server denies access to resources.

The web.config:

On the IIS side enable Anonymous Authentication

The authetication/authorization relies on Owin trough OKTA openid sessions, just secure the controller using the [Authorize] atribute.

Here some of the sources
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx
https://clouddevelop.wordpress.com/2015/11/27/asp-net-mvc-owin-external-authentication-made-easy/
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aspnet-mvc-example